# "Super expression must either be null or a function" with Vue 3 + vue-property-decorator

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I'm trying to create a new project with Vue 3 and TypeScript. For that I want to use vue-property-decorator because I like the class syntax with Decorators.

I used the Vue CLI to create a new Vue 3 + TypeScript project.

Now if I try to add vue-property-decorator imports to a Vue component, I get the error "Super expression must either be null or a function" in the browser console. My component looks like this:

```
<template>
   <div>Hi</div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Vue, Prop } from "vue-property-decorator";

export default class App extends Vue {
   @Prop(Number) readonly propA: number | undefined;
   @Prop({ default: "default value" }) readonly propB!: string;
   @Prop([String, Boolean]) readonly propC: string | boolean | undefined;
}
</script>
```

The script is just the first example from the module's documentation copy-pasted into my App.vue. Then my main.ts looks like this:

```
import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";

createApp(App).mount("#app");
```

I don't see where in this little piece of code my bug could be coming from. No other components, router or similar are imported anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does adding `@Component` above the "export default class" part solve your problem?

```
import { Vue, Prop, Component } from "vue-property-decorator";
@Component
export default class App extends Vue {
```

EDIT: Ah, from what I can see vue-property-decorator doesn't support Vue 3 officialy yet. There's a release candidate version (version 10) that supports it though.

https://github.com/kaorun343/vue-property-decorator/blob/next/CHANGELOG.md

Comment: I had seen that release candidate before, but didn't realize `npm install vue-property-decorator` had installed the vue2-compatible release. I had to explicitly use `npm install vue-property-decorator@10.0.0-rc.2`. So that's on me for not understanding npm install correctly...

Comment: That's because when you write `npm install vue-property-decorator` npm will install the version that has the `latest` tag. Write `npm show vue-property-decorator` to see what version the latest tag is. You could've also written `npm install vue-property-decorator@rc` to install the v10